# Loop to populate Excel from other excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 Master Excel Workbook that I need to populate from other excel files.... Basically Open 1 by 1 each file from One folder and copy paste on the Master Workbook... I wrote One macro.. but it still have some flows... I don't know how to make it work

```
Option Explicit
Sub fill()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, mywb As Workbook
Dim sPath As String, sFilename As String
Dim NbRows As Integer, rg As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mywb = Workbooks("C:\Users\cbensoussan.FGC\Desktop\MASTER FOLDER.xlsx")

sPath = "F:\Blotters\OPT\2014\Jan\"       
sFilename = Dir(sPath & "*.xls*")       

Do While Len(sFilename) > 0
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFilename)          

  Range("A2:AO2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    mywb.Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown) + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    wb2.Close False   
    sFilename = Dir

Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You say it still doesn't work. What does it do? What does it not do?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested)

```
Option Explicit
Sub fill()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, mywb As Workbook
Dim sPath As String, sFilename As String
Dim NbRows As Integer, rg As Range, rgCopy as range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'if not already open:
Set mywb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cbensoussan.FGC\Desktop\MASTER FOLDER.xlsx")
'or if already open:
'Set mywb = Workbooks("MASTER FOLDER.xlsx")

sPath = "F:\Blotters\OPT\2014\Jan\"       
sFilename = Dir(sPath & "*.xls*")       

Do While Len(sFilename) > 0
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFilename)          

    with wb2.Activesheet
        Set rgCopy = .Range("A2:AO" & .cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    end with

    mywb.activesheet.cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlUp). _
         Resize(rgCopy.Rows.Count, rgCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rgCopy.Value


    wb2.Close False   
    sFilename = Dir

Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I still have a subscript out of range on `Set mywb = Workbooks("C:\Users\cbensoussan.FGC\Desktop\MASTER FOLDER.xlsx")`... dont know where it comes from

Comment: Is that workbook open? It will need to be (or you'll need to open it in your code), and you'd just reference it using the name. Editing my answer...